# What words can I and can't I write in Scribblenauts?

Tags: scribblenauts

I wonder if there is any dictionary of all the words that I can use in the game.
If so, Where can i find it?

Comment: I think this list will be too long for the arQAde format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a list, but it contains 22 802 words, so I'm going to post a link to it.

[Scribblenauts dictionary list of all 22 802 words](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2009/09/12/scribblenauts-dictionary-list-of-all-22802-words.htm)

And

[Scribblenauts wiki - list of objects](http://scribblenauts.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Objects_in_Scribblenauts)

Comment: Mirrors for the words in case the link goes down: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MErSHLd7) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8716218/raw/374755a610a6f87f8eb59b0b317956d460267413/gistfile1.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to list them all. But my logic would say that it would be based on [Scribblenauts ESRB](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=26980), which is Everyone 10+.

Everyone 10+ [states](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/ratings_guide.jsp):

> Content is generally suitable for ages 10 and up. May contain more cartoon, fantasy or mild violence, mild language and/or minimal suggestive themes.

So everything that comes is in a higher category, for example, Mature, which allow blood, gore, etc, would not be allowed in the game.